# Make index.php behave as a directory

Tags: php, system-administration

Some sites (for example, certain implementations of mediawiki,) have a uri format of `http://example.com/index.php/SOME_PAGE`.  How is this done?  Is index.php just a directory on the server that happens to be named like a php file and that actually contains a file named `SOME_PAGE`?    If so, why name it like that?  If not (i.e. it actually *does* represent some sort of legitimate PHP file), then what would the contents of the look like?

Answer (score 12):

This feature is called path info (see [Apache directive `AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)).

When enabled, Apache writes the rest of the requested URI path that’s already mapped to an existing file or directory in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable. So if `/index.php/SOME_PAGE` is requested and `/index.php` is an existing file, the request is mapped to that file and the rest of the path after `/index.php` (`/SOME_PAGE`) is then available in the `PATH_INFO` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not behaving like a directory, it just looks like it is.

index.php is a regular php file.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.evanbot.com/article/fancy-urls-without-mod_rewrite/3) on how to do this with only PHP code. The issue with this is that you are only getting values and you have meaningless key's in your code.

Example from the tutorial, is he is calling index.php/about/Evan/2

To get `about` from the url, he fetches

```
$url[0]
```

That's not very meaningful is it?

Comment: well it depends how you use it really.

Comment: URLs don’t have “directories”. They just have path segments. And when your URLs have a hierarchical structure, you sure can determine what a certain path segment of a certain URL path means. So there is no need to use something like `/foo/about/bar/Evan/baz/2`, `/foo:about/bar:Evan/baz:2` or `/index.php?foo=about&bar=Evan&baz=2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Often, it is also done using a .htaccess file and mod_rewrite.

See [this article](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "AcceptPathInfo" directive used in Apache (directly in httpd.conf or via .htaccess).  It is a long time since I have used PHP / Apache, and even longer since I did this kind of url prettification, but it is essentially a way of passing extra data into index.php without the "normal" html syntax of ?var1=foo&var2=bar

Note, when I did it, I set up a script called 'dynamic' (or similar) as being the default, PHP parsed handler, and made my URLs look like http://hostname/dynamic/value1/value2

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Those sites rewrite incoming requests to point to the actual resources on the server using web server modules such as apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).